Serializer for class foo is not found. Please ensure that class is marked as '@Serializable' and that the serialization compiler plugin is applied
This question has been here countless times, but I just can't figure this one out.
I followed the documentation and other SO answers.
// My class
@Serializable
class DSFile(val name: String, val data: ByteArray)

// build.gradle
ext {
    kotlin_version = '1.9.24'
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version"
}


// app/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.3"
}

IDE doesn't complain about anything. In runtime I get
Serializer for class DSFile is not found. Please ensure that class is marked as '@Serializable' and that the serialization compiler plugin is applied.

I have applied the plugin and added it to my classpath. The version is the same as Kotlin version, annotation has been used in the class. What else am I missing?
Higher version of org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.3 requires kotlin 2.0 and that's not an option for me.

refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71988144/serializer-for-class-is-not-found-mark-the-class-as-serializable-or-prov

@sasikumar yes, I have read this one. If you actually look at my code, you will see that I applied the answer.

How does this question have 12,000 views in 18 hours?

@Tenfour04 I was also shocked

@Tenfour04 The xxx in the title is the cause, I suggested an edit. You seem to have good SEO skills, 100k views is exceptional for the phenomena. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396005/why-does-my-question-get-this-many-views/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/431084/this-question-gets-10k-views-per-day-but-no-interactions/

@Mo_ Interesting, thanks for the insight. That was definitely not my intention. I will avoid doing that in the future.

The official steps didn't work for me.
From the official documentation: (Under "Using apply plugin (the old way)")

Then you can apply plugin (example in Groovy):
apply plugin: 'kotlin' // or 'kotlin-multiplatform' for multiplatform projects
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

Replace
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

with
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'

Then the serialization plugin works

Makes me wonder if the Kotlin IDE plugin you have installed might be outdated.

@Tenfour04 As far as I know that is bundled in Android Studio, isn't it? I have AS Koala with kotlin plugin version 241.15989.150.2411.11948838-AS

Yes, recent versions of AS keep it up to date, so that’s not your problem.
